# Laravel force www and HTTPS error: redirect to index.php

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, https

I have the following `.htaccess` for my Laravel app:

```
ServerSignature Off
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # 1. Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # 2. Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # 3. Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # 4. Redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # 5. Redirect http(s)://example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I want to force `www.` domain and HTTPS. When I introduce in the browser `example.com/myurl`, the server redirects to `https://www.example.com/index.php` instead to `https://www.example.com/myurl`.

I think the problem is in the point 4 or 5, but I can't found it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the order of the directives is the solution:

```
ServerSignature Off
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # redirect http(s)://example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```